# Can't upload file using php

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file using following code but the file is not getting saved in the desired location and no error is being popped out.

The php code is as follows`

```
<?php

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);

      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
?>
```

The html code is

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="index.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code has plenty of echos in it - exactly what is it printing out? Does the target directory have the right permissions?

Comment: Can you add error_reporting(E_ALL); on top of your script and check the result for errors?

Comment: print_r($_FILES); what does that return

Comment: Following is being printed
Upload: y.tab.h
Type: application/octet-stream
Size: 2.4248046875 Kb
Temp file: /tmp/phpBDwqP0
Stored in: upload/y.tab.h

Comment: @Dagon ( [file] => Array ( [name] => y.tab.h [type] => application/octet-stream [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpGulWSJ [error] => 0 [size] => 2483 ) )

Comment: @jordi12100 Adding error_reporting(E_ALL); does not print any error and make no effect.

Comment: It says the file has been stored on that folder. What is the problem? Is the file missing?

Comment: check the permissions on the directory.

Comment: I also have tmp and upload folder in the directory, but no file is getting saved.

Comment: Check if you have permissions to write on the folder. You are echoing without knowing if the file was really moved.

Comment: Permissions are     drwxr-xr-x

Comment: Changing permissions to 777 solved the problem. Thanks all of you.

Comment: Not really a solution as this opens a security hole. Now anyone can read/write/execute on that folder. You should make it writable by Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Check user permissions of the folder you want to store file to.